# Xcode: Interface Builder using wrong destination to render IBDesignable

Tags: swift, interface-builder, macos-catalina, xcode11.3

**Environment**

- macOS: 10.15.3
- Xcode: 11.3.1

  - Swift: 5.1
  - Application Target: macOS

**Background**

I have an IBDesignable control based on NSView (or UIView depending on the desired target).  I have packaged it using Package Manager as follows:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyControl",
    platforms: [
        .macOS(.v10_13),
        .iOS(.v10)
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MyControl",
            targets: ["MyControl"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "MyControl",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyControl Tests",
            dependencies: ["MyControl"]),
    ]
)
```

As part of "MyControl", I have the following typealiases based on the desired destination Target

```
#if os(macOS)
    import AppKit
    public typealias QJViewController = NSViewController
    public typealias QJColor = NSColor
    public typealias QJFont = NSFont
    public typealias QJView = NSView
#elseif os(iOS) || os(tvOS)
    import UIKit
    public typealias QJViewController = UIViewController
    public typealias QJColor = UIColor
    public typealias QJFont = UIFont
    public typealias QJView = UIView
#endif
```

The Package compiles successfully; the control imports into my destination project correctly; everything compiles and functions as expected in the destination project.

**The Problem**

When I setup the control in InterfaceBuilder, it fails to render with the following error:

[image]

To reiterate: My Target is **not** appleTV, it is macOS.  Regardless of what I do, IB wants to render this package, and hence my control, with AppleTV as the destination.  Given the typealiases I use above, the control fails to render correctly because (obviously) macOS knows nothing about UIColor, UIFont, UIView, UIViewController.

**Question**

Is there a way to force IB to use a particular destination when rendering a control?  If not, is there something I am missing from my project setup?  Like I said, the control works as expected; I would just like it to render in IB.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue...
My Package will run only under iOS (specified in the manifest), and the IBDesignable works in a normal project but inside a Swift Package IB tries to render for tvOS...
Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue... I've defined iOS as the only platform available in my Package.swift file but IB is still trying to render it on tvOS. Crazy.

Answer (score 1):

`Cause provided materials are not enough to test the issue, just suggestion - try instead the following conditional mapping

```
#if canImport(AppKit)
    import AppKit
    public typealias QJViewController = NSViewController
    public typealias QJColor = NSColor
    public typealias QJFont = NSFont
    public typealias QJView = NSView
#elseif canImport(UIKit)
    import UIKit
    public typealias QJViewController = UIViewController
    public typealias QJColor = UIColor
    public typealias QJFont = UIFont
    public typealias QJView = UIView
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, Asperi!  This suggestion 'fixes' the failure in IB.  However, my issue still remains.  My targeted application and destination is macOS; however, IB tries to render the control using "AppleTV 4K" as its destination.  Sadly, I still get the following: "Designables Build Failed".